# NFS Implementation, ubuntu sending empty nfs_fh3?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, udp, nfs

Hi i am trying to write my own NFS Server (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) implementation, so on my first test drive i installed ubuntu on a Virtual pc, then i installed the nfs client and tried to mount my NFS Share, with the following command:

> sudo mount -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 192.168.0.250: /nfs

What happens then is,
First of NFSPROC3_NULL is called, and after that NFSPROC3_GETATTR is called but with a nfs_fh3 of zero bytes!!!

I find nothing about it in the rfc (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1813#page-31).

So im at a loss here why does it call NFSPROC3_GETATTR with a empty file handler, i never provided it with a file handler of zero bytes...?

My first guess was that the nfs client had cached invalid data, but after restarting and even reinstalling the whole virtual pc, it still behaves the same way, am i missing some thing in the specs or is the nfs client doing some thing invalid?

If i instead try to mount the share with xbmc, i can at least browse my directory structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, i was not checking the version correctly, the client was calling with the version nfs version 4... and that version of nfs has a different procedure with the same id as NFSPROC3_GETATTR...

Comment: I'm trying to write my own nfs3 client. I'm implemented the data types and 1 procedure (NFSPROC3_GETATTR) I've compiled it using the rpcgen and I have the client stub. My question is how do I create the GETATTR3args that is required to call the function. Its a struct with a nfs_h3 of opaque type(bytes array) What do I give in that and how do i set it?

Comment: Sorry I sadly can't remember the details as this was over 10 years ago :( also you question seems rpcgen specific, I didn't use any framework instead wrote the whole thing by hand..

Comment: When I did a `mount`I checked the wireshark tcp dump, and there was a lookup and after that a getattr procedure call in which the client sends a `fh`object. My question is simply how does the client gets this `fh`. the lookup response did not have any such fh in it.

Comment: @bradley101 I'm sorry but I don't think I can help you, I don't remember how nfs works any more, I don't even know if I have the code any more..